# Set Siri as AVSpeechSynthesisVoice?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, text-to-speech, siri

In my Swift code I want to set the voice of the "AVSynthesisVoice" to the original Siri voice, not the additional voices you can choose. I can only use their name to identify the voice to use, but can I apply the original Siri voice in my preferred language?

```
let u = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "Hello, I'm Siri!")
u.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(TheSiriVoice)
u.speak()
```

Answer (score 1):

The enhanced Siri voice released in iOS 11 is not available to `AVSpeechSynthesizer`.

Comment: Is an older version of the Siri Voice available? iOS 10 maybe?